# Google Spreadsheet - How to repeat a function for every row inside 1 formula

Tags: google-spreadsheets

[[image]

So I want to make a formula that outputs if a vehicle meets the restriction or not. And I have been using this function in the formula:

`IF(ISBLANK($A$7),,REGEXMATCH($A10,$A$7))`

Is there a way for me to say "Do that for Column A to D" instead of repeating that function in the same formula for each row?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the column '$' lock, apply it for row only. Do (in column A) :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A$7),,REGEXMATCH(A$10,$A7))
```

Then copy & paste to column B,C,D..